# Tree grammar attribute $text not working

Tags: tree, antlr, grammar

anltr 3.4 tree grammar attribute $text problem

```
parser grammar:
additiveExpression 
    :   multiplicativeExpression
        (   
            (   '+'^
            |   '-'^
            )
            multiplicativeExpression
        )* 
    ;

tree grammar:
expression
@init 
{
    $start.setOriginalText($text);//try to record source code
}
    :   ^('+' e1=expression e2=expression)
        {
            //do something
        }
    |   ^('-' e1=expression e2=expression)
        {
            //do something
        }
    ;
```

Example:

1+1+1+1;

```
AST:
   +             $text=1+1+1+1    correct
  + 1            $text=+          wrong
 + 1             $text=+          wrong
1 1
```

I only get correct text for root tree,but not any for subtree.
What should I do?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR 3 only sets the start and stop tokens for the root node of the AST produced by a rule. Since your `additiveExpression` rule contains the `^` operator inside of a closure, multiple roots are produced by the rule.

If your grammar does not *reorder* the nodes appearing in the AST, then you can call [`CommonTree.setUnknownTokenBoundaries()`](http://www.antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/tree/CommonTree.html#setUnknownTokenBoundaries%28%29) on the root tree returned by your whole parse operation. This method will recalculate the start and stop token indexes for the entire tree, but could produce strange results if you use rewrite rules (depending on how they're used).